# PAYPAL PHP SDK OrdersCaptureRequest error with statusCode 422

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

### **i use the latest v2 paypal php sdk sandbox and samples with laravel framework, the create order always success but when capture the order it always fails**

### and return this error:

```
"{"name":"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY",
"details":[
{"issue":"COMPLIANCE_VIOLATION",
"description":"Transaction cannot be processed due to a possible compliance violation. To get more information about the transaction, call Customer Support."}],
"message":"The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.",
"debug_id":"d701744348160",
"links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-COMPLIANCE_VIOLATION","rel":"information_link","method":"GET"}]}
```

### **my web.php file :**

```
Route::get('capture_order', 'PayController@capture_order')->name('capture_order');
Route::get('create_order', 'PayController@create_order')->name('create_order');
Route::get('cancel', 'PayController@cancel')->name('payment.cancel');
Route::get('return', 'PayController@return')->name('payment.return');
Route::get('success', 'PayController@success')->name('payment.success');
```

### **& the PayController :**

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
  
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\PayPalHttpClient;
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\SandboxEnvironment;
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\OrdersCreateRequest;
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\OrdersCaptureRequest;

class PayController extends Controller
{
    public $clientId;
    public $clientSecret;
    public $client;
    public $cancel_url = 'http://localhost:8000/cancel';
    public $return_url = 'http://localhost:8000/return';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $mode = config('paypal.mode', 'sandbox');
        if ($mode == "live")  {
            $this->clientId     = config('paypal.live.client_id');
            $this->clientSecret = config('paypal.live.client_secret');
        } else {
            $this->clientId     = config('paypal.sandbox.client_id');
            $this->clientSecret = config('paypal.sandbox.client_secret');
        }

        $environment = new SandboxEnvironment($this->clientId, $this->clientSecret);
        $this->client = new PayPalHttpClient($environment);
    }


    private function buildRequestBody()
    {
        return [
            'intent' => 'CAPTURE',
            'application_context' =>[ "cancel_url" => $this->cancel_url,
                                       "return_url" => $this->return_url],
    
            'purchase_units' =>
                [
                    0 => [
                            'amount' =>
                                [
                                    'currency_code' => 'USD',
                                    'value' => '20'
                                ]
                        ]
                ]
            ];
    }


    public function create_order()
    {
        $request = new OrdersCreateRequest();
        $request->prefer('return=representation');
        $request->body = $this->buildRequestBody();

        try {
            $response = $this->client->execute($request);
            foreach ($response->result->links as $key => $value) {
                if ($value->rel == "approve") 
                {
                    return redirect($value->href);
                }
            }
        }catch (\Exception $ex) {
            echo $ex->statusCode;
            print_r($ex->getMessage());
        }

    }

    public function capture_order(Request $request)
    {
        // if ($request->token) {
            $request = new OrdersCaptureRequest($request->token);
            $request->prefer('return=representation');
            try {
                $response = $this->client->execute($request);
            }catch (\Exception $ex) {
                echo $ex->statusCode;
                dd($ex->getMessage());
            }
        // }
     
    }

   
   
    /**
     * Responds with a welcome message with instructions
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function cancel(Request $request)
    {
        dump($request->all());
        dd('Your payment is canceled. You can create cancel page here.');
    }
  
 

    /**
     * Responds with a welcome message with instructions
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function return(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->token) {
            return redirect()->route('capture_order', [
                'token' => $request->token,
                'PayerID' => $request->PayerID
            ]);
        }
        
        dd($request->all());
    }
}
```

**i use paypal php sdk with a sandbox account.**

### **can i use the old paypal version or it's completely deprecated ?**

### waiting your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### i call the support and the response was:

Funds received into Egyptian accounts need to be automatically withdrawn to an attached funding source, such as a bank.  You can set this up by **going** into the account **settings** section of the account, then the "**money, banks and cards**" section and at the bottom of that page you'll find "**automatic withdrawal**" where you can specify a financial instrument to use for automatic withdrawals -- https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessmanage/account/money

thanks for u all :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

> COMPLIANCE_VIOLATION

This problem is most likely related to the country of the receiving sandbox Business account. [Create a new account](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts) for a different country such as US, then create [a new REST app](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications) that uses that sandbox account, and test its sandbox clientid/secret in sandbox mode instead.

For later use in live mode, ensure that if the live business account is from one of the [countries that require it](https://www.paypal.com/eg/webapps/mpp/ua/recpymt-full), that the live account has a valid auto sweep withdrawal method active and enabled on the account, such as a US bank or local visa card. If you need help configuring auto sweep for live mode, contact PayPal's business support

Comment: i used a different sandbox Business account with US country and different application with this account but the same response.

Comment: is the old php sdk available for use ?

Comment: I don't believe you correctly made the change. Update your question with the response you are receiving with the new account.

Comment: Separately, the deprecated PHP SDK should not be used for anything and has no relation to this problem, which is with the account and app being used.